# Why am I getting garbage value here although i provided argument?

Tags: c++, class, object, area

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Triangle
{
public:
    int a, b, c;
    void getdata();
    int peri(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return a + b + c;
    }
    float s;
    float area;
    float Area(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        s = (a + b + c) / 2;
        area = sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
        cout << area;
    }

};

void Triangle::getdata()
{
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
}

int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    cout << "Enter the three sides";
    Triangle t1;
    t1.getdata();
    cout << "The area of that triangle is " << t1.Area(x, y, z) << "and the perimeter "
         << t1.peri(x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, this code is giving me garbage value although there is no compile error. It is not giving me the desired output of area and perimeter. So why am I getting garbage value?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly indent your code. The code, as it's currently formatted, is very hard to follow along with.

Comment: Why are you passing arguments to `Area` and `peri` when you've stored the input data in member variables? The variables you are passing are uninitialized as well. The `Area` function also does not return a value. You should get a compile warning for that if you have them turned up high enough.

Comment: You don't need `int x,y,z;`; you never initialise them. You don't need `int peri(int a,int b,int c)`, your triangle has `a,b.c` of its own. Replace with `int peri()`. Same about `Area`. Why does `peri` return the value but `Area` prints the value and returns nothing? Why is `Area` capitalised but `peri` is not? Why `s` and `area` are class members even though you initialise and use them in a single function?

Comment: ` s = (a + b + c) / 2;` will truncate due to integer division. Oops. Use `0.5f * (a + b + c)`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yea i got the issue...So i dont have to pass the arguments to member function when I took the member variables as input? right?

Comment: that's one of the issues

Answer (score 6):

Here you initialise **a, b, c** from triangle:

```cpp
void Triangle::getdata( )
{
   cin>>a>>b>>c;
}
```

But here you use **x, y, z** that are not initialised, there is the problem

```cpp
int main()
{
   int x,y,z; //<-- these three variables are nowhere initialised
   cout<<"Enter the three sides";
   Triangle t1;
   t1.getdata();
   cout<<"The area of that triangle is "
      <<t1.Area( x, y, z) //where x, y, z are initialised??
      <<"and the perimeter " 
      <<t1.peri(x,y,z);  //where x, y, z are initialised?
   return 0;
}
```

Update 1: As pointed by @Bathsheba  `s = (a + b + c) / 2;` will truncate due to integer division. Oops. Use 0.5f * (a + b + c). –

This is how you should implement your triangle

```cpp
class Triangle
{
public:
    int a, b, c;
    void getdata();
    int peri() //remove the arguments, the class has its own members to use
    {
        return a + b + c;
    }
    float s;
    float area;
    float Area() //remove the arguments, the class has its own members to use
    {
        s = 0.5f * (a + b + c); //As pointed by @Bathsheba
        area = sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
        cout << area;
    }

};
```

And then write main function like this

```cpp
int main()
{
   //no additional x, y, z
   cout<<"Enter the three sides";
   Triangle t1;
   t1.getdata();
   cout<<"The area of that triangle is "
      <<t1.Area() //no arguments
      <<"and the perimeter " 
      <<t1.peri();  //no arguments
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will upvote if you point out the issue with `s = (a + b + c) / 2;`. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @armagedescu Thanks a lot....Yes its working now giving me desired output.

Comment: @Bathsheba ...I didnt get any issue with s=(a+b+c)/2 becoz s is already float...

Comment: @ISHAGHUGE From my experience I had such problems as well before. Now the compilers are much more intelligent. But in older versions of compiler, if first operand was an int, it was very likely the whole result of operation was and int, and converted to float only on assignment operation.

Comment: @armagedescu  ohh I see...I am a beginner  in coding...so facing such issues..

Comment: @ISHAGHUGE: Hogwash. It doesn't matter that you assigning to a float, (a + b + c) / 2 is performed in integer arithmetic. See for yourself trivially with a and b set to 2 and c set to 3. These rules are set by the C++ standard. No conforming compiler does it in any other way, however intelligent it purports to be.